# String.replaceAll() replacing all characters Instead of just the regex. - Java

Tags: java, replaceall

I am trying to get the IP address of an incoming connection and then store it in a YML file (the SnakeYML API).
I have receiving the IP down pat, and I tested with a incoming local connection that correctly returned "127.0.0.1".

However, when I run this method on it:

```
address.replaceAll(".", "-");
```

The return is this: "---------"
(I have to replace the periods because SnakYML uses periods as path separators)

It's probably something really stupid, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Believe it or not, IntelliJ IDEA actually has a *warning* for your code, along with the suggestion how to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `"\\."` instead of `"."`.  The reason is that `.` is a regular expression that matches any character.  So you need to escape it to make it match only an actual dot - write `address.replaceAll("\\.", "-");`.

An alternative would be to use the `replace` method in place of `replaceAll`, which interprets its arguments literally, instead of as regular expressions.  So `address.replace(".", "-");` will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it would be something simple like that, but I didn't know that a . was a regular expression in that method.

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` uses regex and in regex `.` represents *any character* (except line separators) so you need to escape `.`, for instance via `"\\."` or `"[.]"` (one element [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)).

But clearer and probably faster way would be using `replace(char, char)` like

```
address = address.replace('.', '-');
```

which doesn't use regex engine.

You can also use `replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` which will automatically escape all regex metacharacter from both arguments (yes, `replacement` can also have some special characters which can be used by regex engine).